# PowerShell parse xml and save changes

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm parsing a csproj file for a nuget install and I've got a node that needs to be altered. The node in question is the node named "Generator" where it's value equals "TextTemplatingFileGenerator" and it's parent node has an attribute of "WebConfigSettingsGeneratorScript.tt" (the second part isn't in here yet).

Here's the script that I've got, but it's not quite done. It's working, but it saves an empty file. Also, it doesn't have the 2nd part of my where clause, which is

```
$path = 'C:\Projects\Intouch\NuGetTestPackage\NuGetTestPackage'
cd $path
$files = get-childitem -recurse -filter *.csproj
foreach ($file in $files){
    ""
    "Filename: {0}" -f $($file.Name)
    "=" * ($($file.FullName.Length) + 10)   

    if($file.Name -eq 'NuGetTestPackage1.csproj'){
        $xml = gc $file.FullName | 
        Where-Object { $_.Project.ItemGroup.None.Generator -eq 'TextTemplatingFileGenerator' } | 
        ForEach-Object { $_.Project.ItemGroup.None.Generator = '' }
        Set-Content $file.FullName $xml
    }   
}
```

Here's a basic version of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="T4\WebConfigSettingGeneratorScript.tt">
      <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>WebConfigSettingGeneratorScript.txt</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
```

Thanks a lot. I'm a total PowerShell n00b!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As @empo says, you need to cast the output of `gc $file.FullName` to [xml] e.g. `$xml = [xml](gc $file.FullName)`. And then after making the change but before looping to the next file, you need to save the file e.g. `$xml.Save($file.FullName)`.

This works with the sample project you provided:

```
$file = gi .\test.csproj
$pattern = 'TextTemplatingFileGenerator'
$xml = [xml](gc $file)
$xml | Where {$_.Project.ItemGroup.None.Generator -eq $pattern} |
       Foreach {$_.Project.ItemGroup.None.Generator = ''}
$xml.Save($file.Fullname)
```

Comment: This helps, but $xml.Save($file.FullName) is coming up as an Invalid Operation.

Comment: The only exception XmlDocument.Save(string path) is documented to throw is a XmlException if the corresponding XmlDocument is not well formed. BTW you should also get rid of the `Set-Content $file.FullName $xml` since the `$xml.Save($file.Fullname)` call will save back over the original file.

Comment: Great, I've taken the changes that you have offered. But, it doesn't seem to be making the change to the file.  However, the script IS saving the file.

Comment: The issue with this script is really just that my XML is more complicated than the bit that I provided and that's the real issue. Here's a simpler version of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049323/how-do-i-edit-xml-using-powershell

Comment: @DonRolling did you find out why the .csproj file was overwritten? I have the same issue when trying to update my .csproj file using NuGet package script tools\install.ps1

Comment: @MariuszIgnatowicz this post was from over eight years ago and I don't remember anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Are you missing a cast?

```
$xml = [xml] gc $file.FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, now my change is working:

```
    $fileName = “C:\sovgarde\updates.xml”;
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $fileName);

$child = $xml.CreateElement('option')
$child.SetAttribute('name', 'CHECK_NEEDED')
$child.SetAttribute('value','false')
If ($xml.application.component.option.name -icontains "CHECK_NEEDED") {
    
    $xml.SelectNodes("//option[@name=`"CHECK_NEEDED`"]") | % {$_.ParentNode.removechild($_) }
    #$xml.Save($fileName)   
    
}
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//component')
$node.AppendChild($child)
$xml.Save($fileName)
```